# Design pattern for players

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Is there a design pattern for multimedia players? I've been searching on internet, but I've found no pattern related to architecture of players. I took a look at sources of a few players(MPlayer VLC), however I couldn't recognize any pattern used by the players. I would like to build a player where the different medias supported were implemented in different modules. The player would be an unique process(server) that should be used by a plenty of other client process, the client would request the player to play a media and then the request would be processed by the player.

Answer (score 5):

I dont know if its just my negative thinking about that design-pattern megahype which leads to absolute nonsense behaviour (personal opinion insight), but:

You should not ask yourself "what Design-Pattern could fit for that XYZ type of application i want to code".

This is the absolute wrong way of doing things. Design-Patterns are no lego-blocks which you assign to a program you code. A pattern will naturally evolve in the specific domain.

If you know patterns, it may help you to see what might be a good solution. But in no way you pack some patterns together just for the sake of it.

Patterns for a mmplayer is really a bad question. You might say you need different codecs for the same tasks, wich might evolve in Factory pattern in THAT SPECIFIC DOMAIN. You might want some streaming functionality with some fault tolerance, wich might evolve in a leaky bucket counter.

You might rethink your question. I think it doesnt make sense at all to ask that.

Really, no offense! But i think you are going into the wrong direction in sense of design-decisions. It might be the best to approach it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

A media player is a whole application. There is no such thing as a "design pattern" for an entire application.

However, some families of softwares (say, video games) almost always share some common architectural properties. But we are at the application architecture level here, not at the design pattern one, which is commonly considered as a code level concept.

I'm afraid there is no reference architecture for a media player kind of application, but yet, you can rely on many different and less specific architectural principles. For example, designing a composite application is quite a general practice. You'll find a lot of dedicated literature about how to create a plugin system that can load module, or codec, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Audacity architecture and see a good SW design at the same domain: http://www.aosabook.org/en/audacity.html

> Audacity is a popular sound recorder and audio editor. It is a capable
>   program while still being easy to use. The majority of users are on
>   Windows but the same Audacity source code compiles to run on Linux and
>   Mac too.